# ButtonDown event does not work sometimes matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two textboxes and a button in matlab. Designed the form using GUIDE. I used the following code to copy value from one textbox to another. The code works sometimes and not always. I am not able to find the scenario in which it works and what was wrong with this code.

```
function pushbutton1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
myTextBox1 = findobj('Tag','edit1');
myTextBox2 = findobj('Tag','edit2');
str = get(myTextBox1,'String');
set(myTextBox2,'String',str);
```

Comment: Is this the create function of the `pushbutton`?

Comment: no.. i get this function opened when i right click on the button and select callback-> on button down (something like that)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are there errors?

Comment: i didn't get any error. But it works sometimes only.. dont know why does not work sometimes..

Comment: when i click on the button the values are not copied.. i have given '0' as String for 'edit1' and 'rs.txt' as String for 'edit2' in the property window during UI designing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when i gave the code in pushbutton1_Callback(...) function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments it is safe to say that nothing is wrong with this piece of code.

This is not yet a solution, but it seems clear that you are searching in the wrong place.

Two things that you want to check:

- The state your program is in at the time the function is called, maybe there is something strange going on with the relevant variables.
- Whether there is a problem with the availability of files that you use as input, if you use a file right after it is updated this may be a cause of problems.